# ASP.NET GridView Multiple Edit Rows At Same Time

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit, rowstate

In ASP.NET 4.0 GridView, is it possible to have multiple rows in edit mode at the same time?

I'm controlling the rows with edit mode in a property:

```
Private Property Editing As List(Of Integer)
   Get
       If ViewState("Editing") Is Nothing Then ViewState("Editing") = New List(Of Integer)
       Return CType(ViewState("Editing"), List(Of Integer))
   End Get
   Set(value As List(Of Integer))
       ViewState("Editing") = value
   End Set
End Property
```

Populating it when the user clicks on edit button:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Edit" Then
        Dim row = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Editing.Add(row.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

And changing the RowState property manually in the RowDataBound event:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If Editing.Contains(e.Row.RowIndex) Then
            Then e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But it's not working, the rows is being rendered in the normal state... any ideias?

---

EDIT 2: PROPERTY

MultipleEditGridView.vb:

```
Namespace ClubeCheckIn.UI

        Public Class MultipleEditGridView
            Inherits GridView

            Protected Property IsRowInEditMode(rowIndex As Int32) As Boolean
                Get
                    If ViewState("GridRowEditIndices") Is Nothing Then
                        Return False
                    Else
                        Dim indices = DirectCast(ViewState("GridRowEditIndices"), List(Of Int32))
                        Return indices.Contains(rowIndex)
                    End If
                End Get
                Set(value As Boolean)
                    If ViewState("GridRowEditIndices") Is Nothing Then
                        ViewState("GridRowEditIndices") = New List(Of Int32)
                    End If
                    Dim indices = DirectCast(ViewState("GridRowEditIndices"), List(Of Int32))
                    indices.Remove(rowIndex)
                    indices.Add(rowIndex)
                End Set
            End Property

        End Class

    End Namespace
```

web.config:

```
<controls>
    <add tagPrefix="clube" namespace="ClubeCheckIn.UI" />
</controls>
```

ASPX:

```
<clube:MultipleEditGridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEdit" runat="server" Visible="<%# IsRowInEditMode(Container.DataItemIndex) %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
    </Columns>
</clube:MultipleEditGridView>
```

ERROR:

Error: BC30451: 'IsRowInEditMode' is not declared. It can be inacessible due to the protection level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the `GridView` does not support multiple rows in edit-mode.

As a work around you can use the `ItemTemplate` for both states (f.e. a `Label` and a `TextBox`). Then you can use a property `EditMode` with `RowIndex` as argument. You can store the rows in edit-mode in `ViewState`.

(not tested)

```
Protected Property IsRowInEditMode(rowIndex As Int32) As Boolean
    Get
        If ViewState("GridRowEditIndices") Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        Else
            Dim indices = DirectCast(ViewState("GridRowEditIndices"), List(Of Int32))
            Return indices.Contains(rowIndex)
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        If ViewState("GridRowEditIndices") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("GridRowEditIndices") = New List(Of Int32)
        End If
        Dim indices = DirectCast(ViewState("GridRowEditIndices"), List(Of Int32))
        indices.Remove(rowIndex)
        indices.Add(rowIndex)
    End Set
End Property
```

you could call it directly from the markup, f.e. for the edit-controls:

```
Visible='<%# IsRowInEditMode(Container.DataItemIndex) %>
```

Comment: You mean creating two asp:panel, one contaning the labels and the other containing the textboxes?

Comment: @Fernando: No. You just need two controls for each mode and switch the visibility according to the mode, you can even call the property from the aspx like: `Visible='<%# IsRowInEditMode(Container.DataItemIndex) %>'` (not tested). Every column's ItemTemplate contains then both controls but only one is visible.

Comment: I inserted this property in a custom server control but the page don't recognize it... there's a way to do it?

Comment: @Fernando: What means "it doesn't recognize" it? You can set it from codebehind and read it from aspx, can't you?

Comment: It's not in the code behind, it's in a custom server control: Public Class MultipleEditGridView Inherits GridView Protected Property IsRowInEditMode(rowIndex As Int32) As Boolean...

Comment: @Fernando: A server control also has a codebehind. What means "the page doesn't _recognize_ it"?

Comment: web.config: <controls><add tagPrefix="clube" namespace="ClubeCheckIn.UI" /></controls> ----- aspx: <clube:MultipleEditGridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" /> ----- Error: BC30451: 'IsRowInEditMode' is not declared. It can be inacessible due to the protection level

Comment: @Fernando: I have tried to find the reason but it's been too long since i've used a server control myself. Where/when do you get this exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this that works batter...

```
   Get
        If ViewState("GridRowEditIndices") Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        Else
            Dim indices = DirectCast(ViewState("GridRowEditIndices"), List(Of Int32))
            Return indices.Contains(rowIndex)
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        If ViewState("GridRowEditIndices") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("GridRowEditIndices") = New List(Of Int32)
        End If
        Dim indices = DirectCast(ViewState("GridRowEditIndices"), List(Of Int32))
        indices.Remove(rowIndex)
        indices.Add(rowIndex)
    End Set
End Property
```